# .exe not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. in TFS

Tags: tfs, windows-installer, exe

I need to run an .exe file as part of a build process in TFS. If I try to execute the .exe itself I get this error

DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This .exe is from Visual Studio, and necessary to run so that I'm able to build an msi in TFS, otherwise I get a different error.

I'm incredibly new to all this stuff, so apologies my knowledge is really basic with all this!

Anyone has any idea as to why TFS is not recognizing it or able to run it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your build pipeline?